# Как развернуть html приложение vkontakte на весь экран?!

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, вконтакте

Существуют ли способы увеличения размера html приложения в Вконтакте?! (к примеру на весь экран)
Меня не устраивает максимальное разрешение по ширине в 827 px.

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы разработчик, то разворачивание приложения вконтакте на весь экран - свинство.

На весь экран (для флэша):

```
stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Обратно:

```
stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
```

Для iFrame можно было обратиться к его parent и изменить физические размеры. Но сейчас это прикрыли, к счастью.

Если пользователь - существует множество способов. До недавнего можно было открыть содержимое фрейма. Сейчас можно в файрбаге/аналогичной системе изменить размер контейнера вручную.

Comment: Написанно на html и запускаеться как iframe. Кстати а почем свинство ммм?!

Comment: Потому что теряется связь с основными контролами вконтакта. В том числе, возможна ситуация с полным их замещением, чем могут воспользоваться недобросовестные люди.

Comment: В том что есть ПОЛИТИКА КОНФИДЕНЦИАЛЬНОСТИ согласно которой всё подозрительные/хакерские действия запрещается делать в JavaScript

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения! =)